# What must I cast an `u8` to in able to use it as an index in my vector?

Tags: rust

I have a 2D vector in Rust which I am trying to index with a dynamic `u8` variable. An example of what I'm trying to do is below:

```
fn main() {
    let mut vec2d: Vec<Vec<u8>> = Vec::new();

    let row: u8 = 1;
    let col: u8 = 2;

    for i in 0..4 {
        let mut rowVec: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
        for j in 0..4 {
            rowVec.push(j as u8);
        }
        vec2d.push(rowVec);
    }

    println!("{}", vec2d[row][col]);
}
```

However, I get the error

```
error: the trait `core::ops::Index<u8>` is not implemented for the type `collections::vec::Vec<collections::vec::Vec<u8>>` [E0277]
```

In later versions of Rust, I get

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `u8: std::slice::SliceIndex<[std::vec::Vec<u8>]>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:15:20
   |
15 |     println!("{}", vec2d[row][col]);
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^ slice indices are of type `usize` or ranges of `usize`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::slice::SliceIndex<[std::vec::Vec<u8>]>` is not implemented for `u8`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::ops::Index<u8>` for `std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<u8>>`
```

What must I cast the `u8` to in able to use it as an index in my vector?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Indices are of type `usize`; `usize` is used for sizes of collections, or indices into collections. It represents the native pointer size on your architecture.

This is what you need to use for this to work properly:

```rust
println!("{}", vec2d[usize::from(row)][usize::from(col)]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should cast it as a `usize`, which I find more readable than
 of `your_vector[index_u8]` use `your_vector[index_u8 as usize]`

I personally find `x as usize` to be more readable than `usize::from(x)`, but this is just my preference.
In your case:
`println!(“{}”, vec2d[row as usize][col as usize]);`

This occurs because v[i] is really parsed as `*(&v + i)`, or the value at (the memory address of the vector + the index). Because `&v` is a memory address, i, the index, must also be a memory address type. Rust represents memory addresses of the type `usize`.

I know this has already been answered but I just prefer `x as usize` to `usize::from(x)`. The decision is yours.