# can't cast slices indices into u8 type to be inserted in a macro expecting expression

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I just started coding in `Rust` for 3 days so bear with me. I have a macro declared that needs to take 2 integers to index into a vector and return the value. These 2 integers are to be supplied in the main function from 2 vectors and their values to be plugged in the macro. I know that the type of vector elements are `usize` which need to be casted to `u8` but that didn't work either. Here is the code.

```
macro_rules! dummyMacro {
    ($x:expr, $y:expr) => {
        {
            let table = vec![1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

            table[$x + $y]
        }
    };
}

fn main() {
    let mut vectorOne: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    vectorOne.push(1);
    vectorOne.push(2);
    let mut vectorTwo: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    vectorTwo.push(1);
    vectorTwo.push(2);
    let mut vectorThree: Vec<u8> = vec![0,0];
    vectorThree[0] = dummyMacro!(vectorOne[0], vectorTwo[0]);
    println!("{:?}", vectorThree);    

}
```

The error

```
error[E0277]: the type `[{integer}]` cannot be indexed by `u8`
  --> src/main.rs:10:13
   |
10 |             table[$x + $y]
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ slice indices are of type `usize` or ranges of `usize`
...
49 |     vectorThree[0] = dummyMacro!(vectorOne[0], vectorTwo[0]);
   |                      --------------------------------------- in this macro invocation
   |
   = help: the trait `std::slice::SliceIndex<[{integer}]>` is not implemented for `u8`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::ops::Index<u8>` for `std::vec::Vec<{integer}>`
```

I have seen the following questions and they didn't help

[What is the correct type to use for an array index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230697/what-is-the-correct-type-to-use-for-an-array-index)

[What must I cast an `u8` to in able to use it as an index in my vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28823901/what-must-i-cast-an-u8-to-in-able-to-use-it-as-an-index-in-my-vector)

[Why I can not use u8 as an index value of a Rust array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46102811/why-i-can-not-use-u8-as-an-index-value-of-a-rust-array)

Comment: You need to cast vectorOne[0] as usize, and  vectorTwo[0] as usize.

Comment: Ideally what you have implemented as a macro would be implemented as a function?

Comment: Can you please post the error message + code for the version where you did cast?

Comment: Your question **is** answered by [What must I cast an \`u8\` to in able to use it as an index in my vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28823901/what-must-i-cast-an-u8-to-in-able-to-use-it-as-an-index-in-my-vector). The error stems not from the macro, but from the `u8`s in your main.

Comment: in the actual code, the macro is a vector of size 256*256  and computing it element by element is slower that direct array access

Comment: casting to usize actually worked but it takes forever to be finished

Comment: thank you every thing works now